# Multi-row x-axis with separator inside using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I implement histogram with such complex x-axis?

[image]

First x-axis row is the week start, second - week end.
Data for tests in csv: https://gofile.io/d/FrhLZh.

What I managed to

```
  hist_data %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = week, y = count)) + 
        geom_col(fill = "#5B879E", width = 0.9, size = 0.7) +
      
        labs(title = "", x = "", y = "") +
        
        theme_bw() + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="none")+ 
        theme(
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
          
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          
          axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5, size = 8, family = "Inter", colour = "#ffffff"),
          
          axis.line.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          
          
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#3A464F"),
          plot.margin=unit(c(0,0.25,0.5,0), "cm"))+ 
          scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), labels = format(as.Date(hist_data$week_start), "%d-%m"), position = "bottom") +
        scale_y_continuous()
```

[image]

Comment: Could be helpful: https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#nested-relations-1. Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) and his [ggh4x](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#nested-relations-1) package, solution:

```
   hist_data %>%
   
   ggplot(aes(x = week, y = count)) + 
        geom_col(fill = "#5B879E", width = 0.8, size = 0.7)+
   
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "") +
        
        theme_bw() + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="none")+ 
        theme(
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
          
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          
          axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5, size = 8, lineheight = 0.8, family = "Inter", colour = "#ffffff"),
          
          axis.line.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          
          ggh4x.axis.nestline.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "#5B879E", lineend = "square"),
          
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#3A464F"),
          plot.margin=unit(c(1,0.5,1,0.5), "cm"))+ 
          scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), 
                           labels = paste0(format(as.Date(sort(hist_data$week_start)), "%d.%m"), 
                                           "\n", "nonsense", "\n", 
                                           format(as.Date(sort(hist_data$week_end)), "%d.%m")), position = "bottom") +
        scale_y_continuous() +
  guides(x = guide_axis_nested(delim = "nonsense"))
```

[image]

Comment: But I have a question whether it can be seperated by groups if there are several grouping information. Just like the bars above were seperated into severeal groups, we distinguish them by the space between different groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple layers of `geom_text` and `geom_segment`. Adjust the relative y positions of these layers using a scaling factor.

```
plotscale <- max(hist_data$count)/50

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = hist_data,
       aes(x = week_start + floor(week_end-week_start)/2, y = count)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "#5B879E", width = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(y = -6 * plotscale ,
                label = format(week_start, "%m-%d")),
            color = "#ffffff")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = week_start, xend = week_end,
                y = -10 * plotscale, yend = -10 * plotscale),
            color = "#5B879E", size = 1.5)+
  geom_text(aes(y = -14 * plotscale,
                label = format(week_end, "%m-%d")),
            color = "#ffffff")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#3A464F"))+
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), date_breaks = "1 week",
               labels = NULL)
```

[image]

Consider using [ggh4x](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#nested-relations-1) package for more complex nested x axes.

---

**Raw Data**

```
hist_data <- read.table(text='"","week","count","week_start","week_end"
"1","1",21.5823972708382,2021-01-04,2021-01-10
"2","2",36.122556304552,2021-01-11,2021-01-17
"3","3",34.2809483156697,2021-01-18,2021-01-24
"4","4",25.8546925450454,2021-01-25,2021-01-31
"5","5",29.0309819292706,2021-02-01,2021-02-07
"6","6",33.1503608888827,2021-02-08,2021-02-14
"7","7",27.0490347440184,2021-02-15,2021-02-21
"8","8",30.3031289757874,2021-02-22,2021-02-28
"9","50",32.2876434072602,2020-12-07,2020-12-13
"10","51",33.1939593686481,2020-12-14,2020-12-20
"11","52",26.6853246329896,2020-12-21,2020-12-27
"12","53",23.0715199391151,2020-12-28,2021-01-03', header = TRUE, sep = ",")

hist_data$week_start <- as.Date(hist_data$week_start)
hist_data$week_end <- as.Date(hist_data$week_end)
```